# How to save Bargraph,piechart dynamically in excel

Tags: java, excel, jfreechart

I am creating bar graphs,pie charts using jfreechart and i have to save them in a excel sheet corresponding to the data from which bar graph,pie chart are created.Can anyone help me as to how i can acheive it.I know that we can save bar graphs,piecharts in jpeg,png format but can we save it directly to excel sheet.Since the no of bar graphs and piecharts are many.Please guide me with this.

Comment: A similar question is examined [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116788).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving charts in Excel sheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334068/saving-charts-in-excel-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

For excel sheet use [Apache POI-HSSF and POI-XSSF - Java API To Access Microsoft Excel Format Files](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html).
To download visit [Apache POI library.](http://poi.apache.org/download.html)

Writing image to excel convert it to byte array

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(baos, chart, 700, 350);
byte[] imgByArray = baos.toByteArray();
```

Now, pass this `imgByArray` to method from Apache POI see more [Not able to insert image into excelsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18311467/1031945)

Comment: Hey thanks alot for your help.I was able to insert bargraph in excel.However i am facing another problem.I am inserting four bar graphs in one row and that continues for alot of data that I insert in excel.i am dynamically inserting bargraph.But when it is inserted in excel the image resizes automatically.Can anyone guide me for this?